# Search json key and return empty list if its value is an empty string

Tags: scala

This code doesn't handle empty string values well:

```
val getPerson = (json \ "ID").asOpt[String].map(id => List(Person(name, id, birthday))).getOrElse(List.empty)
```

Problem is that ID can be an empty string, Person's constructor allows id to be empty (by design) but I don't want Persons with no ID at this stage.

I tried:

```
val getPerson = (json \ "ID").asOpt[String].map(id => if (id.nonEmpty) List(Person(name, id, birthday))).getOrElse(List.empty)
```

but then the return type is `Any` instead of `List[Person]`

My goal is in cases of an empty `id` return List.empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the type to `List.empty`, e.g:

```
scala> List.empty[String]
res0: List[String] = List()
```

In your example `filter` may be a nicer solution:

```
val person = (json \ "ID")
                   .asOpt[String]
                   .filter(_.nonEmpty)
                   .toList
                   .map(Person(name, _, birthday))
```

Comment: I need this code to not create a Person if the value of ID is empty. Other then that it works

Comment: To adjust `List.empty[Person]` would fix the problem of `Any` as the return type. So it should do what you want - return an empty List in case there is no ID

Comment: adding `.filter(_.nonEmpty)`  to my original code did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @pme answer, the reason that you should use `List.empty[Type]` (Whether `String` or `Person`) and not `List.empty` is because  `List.empty` is actually of type `List[Nothing]`.

Because you returned `List[Person]` in one case and `List[Nothing]` in the other, you had a return type of `Any`.

Anyway, when you are dealing with empty collections (Seq, List,..), you should always prefer `List/Seq.empty[Type]`, because it's a clearer expression of your intent and it doesn't require the instantiation of an (empty) repeated-params argument list.